# How to loop a function in a sub-directory

Tags: linux, bash, fastq

I cant figure out how to loop a function to combine Fastq files in a sub-directory

The directory is organized as

```
TJU1/Files/Actual files
TJU2/Files/Actual files 
...
```

I can run this code on the sub-directories individually but I cant figure out how to loop it for the "files" sub-directory in each folder

```
cat *R1* > R1.fastq.gz ; cat *R2* > R2.fastq.gz
```

I am new to the BASH command structure so I apologize if this is a basic question.

Would appreciate any help
Thank You

Comment: Please, be more specific. Currently it is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Are you using `cat` to add files to a zipfile???

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
for folder in $(ls -d ROOT_PATH/*/)
do
  cd $folder && cat.......
done
```